# Compilation error: module Ecto.Model is not loaded and could not be found

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto, elixir

Getting the issue on compilation, please have a look, may be anyone is familiar with the error

```
== Compilation error on file web/controllers/order_controller.ex ==
** (CompileError) web/controllers/order_controller.ex:2: module Ecto.Model is     not loaded and could not be found
expanding macro: PhoenixCart.Web.__using__/1
web/controllers/order_controller.ex:2: PhoenixCart.OrderController (module)
(elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.use/2
web/controllers/order_controller.ex:2: PhoenixCart.OrderController (module)
```

## Controller

```
defmodule PhoenixCart.OrderController do
  use PhoenixCart.Web, :controller

  alias PhoenixCart.Order

   plug :scrub_params, "order" when action in [:create, :update]

  def index(conn, _params) do
    orders = Repo.all(Order)
    render(conn, "index.html", orders: orders)
  end
  ##<more code>
end
```

## web.exs //controller part

```
def controller do
    quote do
      use Phoenix.Controller

  # Alias the data repository and import query/model functions
  alias PhoenixCart.Repo

  import Ecto.Model
  import Ecto.Query, only: [from: 2]

  # Import URL helpers from the router
  import PhoenixCart.Router.Helpers
end
```

end

Comment: Which version of Ecto and Phoenix are you using? `Ecto.Model` was removed quite a while ago. If you updated your dependencies manually, did you follow the Phoenix upgrade guides?

Comment: i actually cloned the old project. does it have the guidlines? @Dogbert

Comment: Can you tell us the exact versions of Ecto and Phoenix you're using? They should be there in the file `mix.lock` like this `... "phoenix": {:hex, :phoenix, VERSION, ...} ...`.

Comment: "ecto": {:hex, :ecto, "2.1.2",   
"phoenix": {:hex, :phoenix, "1.2.1",

i removed Model in Ecto.Model, error disappeared. However now i am getting        ** (CompileError) web/models/order.ex:4: undefined function schema/2
 @Dogbert

Comment: Looks like your app was built before v1.1. http://www.phoenixframework.org/blog/upgrading-from-v10-to-v11 includes how to fix `Ecto.Model` and other changes. You'll also probably want to follow the v1.1 to v1.2 guide (link in sidebar on that page).

Comment: Thank you @Dogbert,  removing Model,  as it has been depreciated. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Removed 'Model' in Ecto.Model, as use Ecto.Model has been deprecated and removed

Thank you @Dogbert, for help.

Comment: I had both `Ecto.Model` and `Ecto.Query` imported. I've removed `Ecto.Model` to make it work.